# how convert content mysql from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8-persian-ci

Tags: php, mysql, smf

I have a vb forum with a huge amount of data

I need a way to convert this forum database tables and contetnt charset with thier data from

latin1_swedish_ci to utf8-persian-ci

How to do this ?
my old froum used of SMF 2.0.x and For example, if stored characters

```
ãØÇáÈ ãÑÈæØ Èå ÂãáÛ ÝÇÛÑ ¡ ÕæÊÛ ¡ ãæÓÛÞÛ  ÑÇ ÏÑ ÇÛä ÞÓãÊ ãÑÍ ËäÛÏ
```

The PHP code also tested but did not true

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str= 'ãØÇáÈ ãÑÈæØ Èå Âãáی ÝÇیÑ ¡ ÕæÊی ¡ ãæÓیÞی  ÑÇ ÏÑ Çیä ÞÓãÊ ãÑÍ ˜äیÏ';
$tab = array("UTF-8", "ASCII", "Windows-1252", "ISO-8859-15", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-6", "CP1256");
$chain = "";
foreach ($tab as $i)
    {
        foreach ($tab as $j)
        {
            $chain .= " $i"."->"."$j=".@iconv($i, $j, "$str").'';
        }
    }

echo $chain;
```

Comment: in place of utf-8 write these language codes---> latin1_swedish_ci / utf8-persian-ci

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887446/illegal-mix-of-collations-php-mysql-latin1-swedish-ci-and-utf8-general-ci?rq=1